# Split column in two with Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi

My table has the following structure:

[image]

I need to analyse the variance of views by page title from the periods in column B: 2016 vs 2015.
For that, I'm using Power BI desktop. I'm trying to split column B in two: one with the period 1/jan/2015-19/ago/2015 and other with 1/jan/2015-19/ago/2015

Is this possible to do? How?
I tried unpivoting but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your need correctly you might be able to achieve your result with your same data without the need to split your columns:

Insert a Clustered Column Chart visual.

On the "Axis" field of the visual drag your "Title" column.

On the "Legend" field of the visual drag your "Dates" column.

On the "Value" field of the visual drag your "Views" column and then select "Variance" on the dropdown for "Value".

This should compare the variance of the number of views for each of the pages between the 2015 and the 2016 period.